# Lucene Core to Solr Migration - How to construct JTS Query for Solr

Tags: solr, solrj, solrcloud

We are migrating from Lucene 4.0 to Solr Cloud 8.5.1, and I have a bounding polygon(shape) query that was generated using JTS. `LatLong` has 2 variable `latitude` and `longitude` that are double.

When the `List<LatLong>` points are passed to the method, it checks to see number of points passed and determines on the shape. For example, if only 1 point is passed, it generates a circle using the distance as radius. If more than 2 points are passed, it generates a linerrings etc.

I was able to generate Solr Query when 1 point is passed. How can I generate the Solr Query for LinerRings and other criteria.

```
private List<IndexSearchResult> getResultsInBoundingPolygon(List<LatLong> points, Integer distance) {

    if (points.isEmpty()) {
        return new ArrayList<IndexSearchResult>();
    }

    AirQuerySearcher searcher = (AirQuerySearcher) IndexServiceFactory.getIndexService(
            AirLuceneSearchService.AIR_INDEX_SERVICE).getSearcher();

    
    Shape shape;
    SpatialArgs spatialArgs;
    if(points.size() == 1){
        spatialArgs = new SpatialArgs(SpatialOperation.Intersects,
                searcher.getSpatialCtx().makeCircle(                    
                        points.get(0).getLongitude(), 
                        points.get(0).getLatitude(),
                        DistanceUtils.dist2Degrees(distanceToSearch, DistanceUtils.EARTH_EQUATORIAL_RADIUS_MI)));
    }else{
        if (points.size() > 2) {

            Coordinate[] coords = new Coordinate[points.size() + 1];
            int i = 0;
            for (LatLong point : points) {
                coords[i] = new Coordinate(point.getLongitude(), point.getLatitude());
                i++;
            }
            /*
             * LinearRings apparently need to be closed rings, so this adds a
             * copy of the first point at the end of the list to close the
             * figure.
             */
            coords[points.size()] = new Coordinate(coords[0].x, coords[0].y);
            GeometryFactory fact = new GeometryFactory();
            LinearRing linear = fact.createLinearRing(coords);
            Polygon poly = new Polygon(linear, null, fact);
            shape = (Shape) new JtsGeometry(poly, (JtsSpatialContext) searcher.getSpatialCtx(),true, true);
        } else if (points.size() == 2) {
            /*
             * For two points, generates a circle (technically a configurable
             * n-sided regular polygon defaulting to a dodecagon, but whatever)
             * for each point, then takes the intersection of those and searches
             * within the resulting shape.
             */
            GeometryFactory fact = new GeometryFactory();
            Point point1 = fact.createPoint(new Coordinate(points.get(0).getLongitude(), points.get(0).getLatitude()));
            Point point2 = fact.createPoint(new Coordinate(points.get(1).getLongitude(), points.get(1).getLatitude()));
            Geometry circle1 = point1.buffer(AirSearchConfig.getSinglePointSearchDegreeDiff(),
                    AirSearchConfig.getQuadrantSegments());
            Geometry circle2 = point2.buffer(AirSearchConfig.getSinglePointSearchDegreeDiff(),
                    AirSearchConfig.getQuadrantSegments());
            Geometry overlap = OverlayOp.overlayOp(circle1, circle2, OverlayOp.INTERSECTION);

            shape = (Shape) new JtsGeometry(overlap, (JtsSpatialContext) searcher.getSpatialCtx(), true,true);
        } else {
            shape = searcher.getSpatialCtx().makeCircle(points.get(0).getLongitude(), points.get(0).getLatitude(),
                    AirSearchConfig.getSinglePointSearchDegreeDiff());
        }
        spatialArgs = new SpatialArgs(SpatialOperation.IsWithin, shape);
    }
    Filter filter = searcher.getSpatialStrategy().makeFilter(spatialArgs);
    List<IndexSearchResult> results = searcher.executeQuery(new MatchAllDocsQuery(), filter,
            AirSearchConfig.getMaxResultsInBoundingPolygon(), null, null);
    if (results != null) {
        logger.info("getResultsInBoundingPolygon-> Found " + results.size() + " results");
    } else {
        logger.info("getResultsInBoundingPolygon-> Result is empty");
    }
    
    return results;

}
```

Comment: Your title seems to indicate that this is only related to running in Cloud mode. Is there any difference in how these queries are handled when running in cloud mode vs standalone?

Comment: There is no difference, updating the title. Thanks!